# Why my programe is not going into the if loop in php

Tags: php, html

I wanted to make a simple login page using php and mysql database where I have created table members (id, username, password).

When I run my program, it's not entering the if block and directly moving to else block

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="process.php">
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="username">
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP code is

```
<?php
include("includes/dbConnect.php");


$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=stripcslashes($username);
$username=stripcslashes($password);
$username=$conn->real_escape_string($username);
$password=$conn->real_escape_string($password);

//query
$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' AND password ='$password'";
$result= $conn->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
if($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password)
{
    echo "Welcome";

}
else
{
    echo "fail";

}
?>
```

Please help me out and rectify my error

P.S. I am new to php code so if anyone would like to give me any advice It will be most welcome

Comment: Echo out your if statement before you get there to make sure your variables are what you expect. `echo "{$row['username']}==$username && {$row['password']}==$password";`

Comment: did you try to print the if condition variables. echo $row['username'], $username, $row['password'], $password

Comment: You are assigning your password to your username.

Answer (score 2):

Your second line here:

```
$username=stripcslashes($username);
$username=stripcslashes($password);
```

is mistakenly assigning to the `$username` variable again.

Comment: Thanks I am very ashamed for this silly mistakes

Please do help me if you have any online resources to learn php

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes!  I think that most of my mistakes have been the result of copying & pasting code.